# Запятая в обороте "потому что"

Tags: пунктуация

Разделяется ли запятыми оборот "потому что" в таком случае: "Может, потому(,) что..."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь запятая не нужна.
Союз "потому что" может иметь двоякую пунктуацию - с запятой либо перед "потому", либо перед "что". Но если союз начинает предложение (вводное "может" не учитывается), то запятая перед "что" не ставится.
Как вариант корректно "Может потому, что ...".

Answer (score 5):

Одним из условий расчленения сложных союзов является наличие перед союзом вводного слова. В предложении, начало которого здесь представлено, есть вводное слово МОЖЕТ, поэтому сложный союз расчленяется, между частями этого союза ставится запятая: МОЖЕТ, ПОТОМУ, ЧТО...: "К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся: 1) ...; 2)...; 3) наличие перед союзом вводного слова, например: Всё это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ, ОТТОГО, ЧТО я уже не увижу их... " (Гоголь); В гостях у Пряхиных все чувствовали себя свободно, ВОЗМОЖНО, ПОТОМУ, ЧТО Павла Романовна никого не старалась занимать. (Коптяева)..."
 (См.: Розенталь Д.Э. и др. Справочник по русскому языку. Правописание. Произношение. Литературное редактирование.--- М., 2007. --- С.248)

Comment: Цитату из Розенталя не приведете?
Или хотя бы точные данные книги. Розенталевских справочников - миллион, а искать в сети по издательству очень трудно.  

Вообще пунктуация с двумя запятыми крайне сомнительна.

Comment: В "Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации" (РАН, под ред. Лопатина - кстати,behemothus, Вы на него ссылаетесь, когда говорите " у Лопатина"?) есть пример с разделением союза в начале предложение (Оттого, что...) и с неразделением, так как после союза идет союзное слово. Так что здесь еще и контекста не хватает!

Comment: Здесь я обычно я ссылаюсь на словари как на самодостаточный источник. Или уж провожу более или менее законченную цитату с указанием источника.
Точное место в "Правилах" не укажете?  
Вообще у Лопатина много чего есть, обобщать можно только крепко подумавши.

Comment: А, нашел. § 117 по изданию 2009 г.  
Но союзы могут расчленяться — в зависимости от смысла предложения, логического выделения (усиления) первой части и союза. В этом случае запятая ставится перед второй частью союза, а первая включается в состав главной части как соотносительное слово: *Оттого, что мы встали очень рано и потом ничего не делали, этот день казался очень длинным (Ч.); Благодаря тому, что лето очень жаркое и сухое, понадобилось поливать каждое дерево (Ч.);...*  
(Остальные примеры - не наш случай).  
Здесь трудно возразить. Но это скорее исключение, чем правило. Чехов, однако.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, уже ответили, но запятая нужна, так как есть вводное слово. [Информация с этого сайта](http://texts.net.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF/):

> Если перед «потому что» следует вводное слово или вводная конструкция (которая, напомним, выделяется запятыми с обеих сторон), то запятая ставится после *потому,* а не перед «потому что». Например, он любил ее, как оказалось, потому, что она была умной и красивой.

Comment: Нет, **такого**, слава богу, никто не предлагал. Вы неверно трактуете источник. Если союз расчленяется, то это значит, что ставится **одна** запятая между "потому" и "что". А вот вторая (т. е. первая по тексту, перед "потому") может присутсвовать только по иным мотивам. А нашем случае запятая после "может" сама по себе не нужна ("вводное" в начале предложения - это обычно частица). Поэтому либо - либо. Либо запятая перед "потому", либо после. Две - никак не получается.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#з_02 (Розенталь:

К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся:

3)      наличие перед союзом вводного слова, например: ...Все это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, может быть, оттого, что я уже не увижу их... (Гоголь); В гостях у Пряхиных все чувствовали себя свободно, возможно, потому, что Павла Романовна никого не старалась занимать (Коптяева);

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от акцента на слове - надо произнести фразу вслух, и тогда будет ясно, на что мы ставим ударение. Например, "да потомУ, что мы бы опоздали" , "Вряд ли, потому что всё уже оформлено окончательно". Если оборот этот можно заменить другим - "так как", то абсолютно никаких вопросов не возникает. После "может", "скорее всего", "видимо" итп. запятая перед "что" ставится, т.к. здесь идёт речь о поиске причины, раздумывании при ответе на вопрос "почему?" И всё просто.

Answer (score 0):

"...Все это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, может быть, оттого, что я уже не увижу их... (Гоголь); В гостях у Пряхиных все чувствовали себя свободно, возможно, потому, что Павла Романовна никого не старалась занимать (Коптяева)"

Невзирая на Розенталя и Гоголя, в таком виде эти предложения в русском языке существовать не могут: вводное в сложносочинённых предложениях не отделяется в той части, к которой относится (мало кто об этом помнит).

Так что только: "Все это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, может быть оттого, что я уже не увижу их";
и "В гостях у Пряхиных все чувствовали себя свободно, возможно потому, что Павла Романовна никого не старалась занимать".

Если не учитывать это правило, потеряем смысл - уберите "оттого что" и сравните:
"Все это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, может быть я уже не увижу их"
и 
"Все это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть может быть, я уже не увижу их".
Чувствуете разницу?