# Верно ли расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, вводные-слова

**А может, потому, что она ест красные продукты?**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запятая в обороте "потому что"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be)

Answer (score 1):

**А может, потому, что она ест красные продукты?**

Расчленение союза **при наличии вводного слова**:

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138

3) наличие перед союзом вводного слова:…Всё это имеет для меня неизъяснимую прелесть, **может быть, оттого, что** я уже не увижу их (Г.); Молодые тетеревята долго не откликались на мой свист, **вероятно, оттого, что** я свистел недостаточно естественно (Т.);

Пример: **А может, потому, что** повзрослела моя дочь и стала напоминать юную бабку на той допотопной фотографии. [Дина Рубина. Окна (2011)]